# Concurrent TCP connections on Azure can be upto 500K. Really?

Tags: networking, tcp, azure

Let me be very clear at the outset that I am new to cloud technology. All I know is cloud servers are easily scalable (i.e. adding physical hardware is transparent to applications and users) and unlike in older days application don't need to worry about scalability.

I was just going through [Azure Subscription Limits](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/) and noticed that [Networking Limits](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#networkinglimits) are just amazing. A virtual machine can support 500K concurrent TCP connections.

Now what does this mean to a TCP server application running on Azure? Can it assume that it is going to receive 500K TCP handles? (Unlike in older days TCP server application needed to be developed considering "Max Concurrent Connections" C10K limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the limit on the networking *infrastructure* supporting those VMs, which seems above and beyond any OS-specific limits. The latter would be the same for the OS outside Azure.

You could see it as the limits imposed by your networking gear in front of your servers in a physical hardware environment.